# What's the deal with applied kinesiology?

Tags: alternative-medicine

I'm 8 weeks into a leadership programme led by a man from an innovation leadership company based in Oslo, Norway. Recently the group was introduced to [kinesiology](http://www.kinesiology.net/). I watched a documentary series episode on NRK and kinesiology seemed like BS according to the show. I am interested in a fair and balanced answer from a well educated skeptic: is this just a belief or is it scientifically grounded?

What I experienced was applied kinesiology. He pushed my arm downwards and linked this to my subconsciousness somehow. The question stands. I won't link to their website. I prefer everything being anonymous.

Comment: I suspect they're promoters of "applied kinesiology", which is a pile of alternative medicine nonsense.  Despite the name, it has nothing to do with kinesiology.

Comment: How is this related to school and China?

Comment: Could you link to the innovation program's website? Otherwise I am afraid that this question may get closed as too broad.

Comment: I went further than @Larian. I've put it on hold while we sort out the question and can reopen it. To start with, we need to separate between the science of [kinesiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinesiology), and the alternative to medicine of [Applied Kinesiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_kinesiology). (You may find those background links contain all you need to know.) Then we need a particular claim being made, so we can evaluate it.

Comment: We can't comment on your leadership programme. We can comment on the documentary series if you can tell us what it is called. There are a few standard "applied kinesiology" fake tests - I have done some on stage - regarding how far you can stretch or whether you can withstand a force applied to your arm. We could re-debunk those if it is helpful. We'll just need to find a claim.